# Mongoose search using regex and ignoring special characters

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, express, mongoose

I want to make a serachbar for my site. I'm really new using express and mongoose.

This my code that works fine but in this case it doesn't give matches:

```
Search input:  Mass energy
Entry name:    Mass-energy equivalence
```

This doesn't match because of the dash/hyphen, how can I ignore it in $regex? Or if there is another better way to do this, let me know. Thanks in advance!

**Code**

```
router.get('/search/:search', param('search').not().isEmpty().trim().escape(), async (req, res) => {
  let search = req.params.search.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '');
  const data = await Entry.find({ 
    'name': {
      '$regex':   search,
      '$options': 'i'
    }
  },
  )
  .populate('category')
  .limit(10);
  res.json(data);
});
```

Comment: you may replace end-user word separator (" ") by a regex '.+' instead of removing it. this will result in 'Mass.?energy' regex search string for mongo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @boly38

Adding `replace.replace(" ", '.+')` to search works

```
  let search = req.params.search.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '').replace(" ", '.+');
```